# Show that if $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ is a continuous function, so is the function $|f|:X\to\textbf{R}$ defined by $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, absolute-value

Show that if $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ is a continuous function, so is the function $|f|:X\to\textbf{R}$ defined by $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

According to the definition of continuity, for every $x_{0}\in X$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
x\in X,\,d(x,x_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow ||f(x)| - |f(x_{0})|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $|f|$ is also continuous.

Is the wording of my proof correct? I am curious if there is another way to solve it too.

Comment: It's correct. Or simply, $|\cdot| : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous map, and composition of continuous maps is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the proof my answer was based on:

> **MY ATTEMPT**
>
> According to the definition of continuity, for every $x_{0}\in X$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x\in X$ it holds
> \begin{align*}
> d(x,x_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow ||f(x)| - |f(x_{0})|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \varepsilon
> \end{align*}
> whence we conclude that $|f|$ is also continuous.

Its basically right since it has the key step (application of the reverse triangle inequality $||a|-|b||\le |a-b|$) but you compressed the entire proof into one line that doesn't make much logical sense. What you wrote is not the definition of continuity of $f$, and not of $|f|$, but a sentence that combines everything I mentioned thus far.

Properly written, maybe as a text book might have, it should first have the definition of continuity of $f$, then the above inequality, and then you point out that $|f|$ satisfies the definition of being continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @CalvinKhor! I will edit it in order to include your suggestions.

Comment: @BrickByBrick OK, that would invalidate my answer, so I will include the version I am talking about in my answer